# What is the purpose and basis for the special garments issued to temple-going Mormons?

Tags: history, lds

I understand that there are certain garments which temple-going Mormons are obliged to wear after going through their initial Temple Ceremony.  My question is regarding the basis for this.  When did it originate?  Was it a new revelation from God?  Is it recorded in any LDS Scriptures or the Doctrines & Covenants?  Does it have any relation to the priestly garments worn by Levites in the Old Testament?

I also understand that there are various symbols on them.  What are the specific purposes of those?

*I do not wish to be irreverent here.  That would not be constructive, so please observe the same tone in any answers.*

Comment: All of the below answers are sensitive and well said.

Comment: Also see: http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/temple-garments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "temple garments," as they're commonly known, serve as a constant physical reminder of the covenants that the person wearing them have made.  They are associated with the temple ceremonies, as you noted in the question.  These ceremonies were revealed to Joseph Smith, and as they are not meant for the world in general, the details have not been published in works of scripture meant for the world in general, such as the Doctrine and Covenants.

I have not heard of any doctrine that directly equates them to the Levitical priestly garments, though Boyd K. Packer, of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles, gave an explanation along those lines at one point, in the spirit of analogy and explanation rather than as solid doctrine:

> On one occasion one of the brethren was invited to speak to the faculty and staff of the Navy Chaplains Training School in Newport, Rhode Island. The audience included a number of high-ranking naval chaplains from the Catholic, Protestant, and Jewish faiths.
>
> In the question-and-answer period one of the chaplains asked, “Can you tell us something about the special underwear that some Mormon servicemen wear?” The implication was, “Why do you do that? Isn’t it strange? Doesn’t that present a problem?”
>
> To the chaplain who made the inquiry he responded with a question: “Which church do you represent?” In response he named one of the Protestant churches.
>
> He said, “In civilian life and also when conducting the meetings in the military service you wear clerical clothing, do you not?” The chaplain said that he did.
>
> He continued: “I would suppose that that has some importance to you, that in a sense it sets you apart from the rest of your congregation. It is your uniform, as it were, of the ministry. Also, I suppose it may have a much more important place. It reminds you of who you are and what your obligations and covenants are. It is a continual reminder that you are a member of the clergy, that you regard yourself as a servant of the Lord, and that you are responsible to live in such a way as to be worthy of your ordination.”
>
> He then told them: “You should be able to understand at least one of our reasons why Latter-day Saints have a deep spiritual commitment concerning the garment. A major difference between your churches and ours is that we do not have a professional clergy, as you do. The congregations are all presided over by local leaders. They are men called from all walks of life. Yet they are ordained to the priesthood. They hold offices in the priesthood. They are set apart to presiding positions as presidents, counselors, and leaders in various categories. The women, too, share in that responsibility and in those obligations. The man who heads our congregation on Sunday as the bishop may go to work on Monday as a postal clerk, as an office worker, a farmer, a doctor; or he may be an air force pilot or a naval officer. By our standard he is as much an ordained minister as you are by your standard. He is recognized as such by most governments. We draw something of the same benefits from this special clothing as you would draw from your clerical vestments. The difference is that we wear ours under our clothing instead of outside, for we are employed in various occupations in addition to our service in the Church. These sacred things we do not wish to parade before the world.”
>
> He then explained that there are some deeper spiritual meanings as well, connecting the practice of wearing this garment with covenants that are made in the temple. We wouldn’t find it necessary to discuss these—not that they are secret, he repeated, but because they are sacred.
>
> -- [Preparing to Enter the Holy Temple](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/preparing-to-enter-the-holy-temple/preparing-to-enter-the-holy-temple?lang=eng)

Likewise, the symbols on the garment are meant to serve as reminders of specific spiritual truths.  Exactly what they represent cannot be effectively discussed in a setting such as this, where objectively correct answers are desired above all else, because those who have been through the temple ceremonies are under a strict covenant obligation to not reveal the knowledge gained therein to the world.

This means that anyone who claims to explain their meaning either have not actually received the ceremony and so they are just making it up, or they have received it and, in telling, are willing to break a solemn vow made to God, and thus their explanation cannot be trusted, especially as in practice, those who do are almost invariably doing so for the specific purpose of trying to make the church look bad, which should automatically call their objectivity into question.

Comment: Mason, you always beat me to it! :)

Comment: Thanks, Mason.  As I asked Matt... When did they originate in the LDS church?  Were they introduced by Joseph Smith?

Comment: @Narnian: They were revealed to Joseph Smith fairly early on in the Church's history, I believe during the Kirtland period but possibly earlier.  I'd have to do some research to find out exactly when, which I don't have time for at the moment. Maybe Matt knows.  If not, I'll look it up tonight after work.

Comment: PS. I only know it after looking it up... my research is usually shallow because I also don't get home until the evening. Feel free to be more comprehensive.

Comment: I just noticed and thought I'd share a link to that explanation above. It's from both Boyd K Pakcer's book *The Holy Temple* and the [booklet that summarizes the same book](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/preparing-to-enter-the-holy-temple/preparing-to-enter-the-holy-temple?lang=eng).
You'll find the discussion in the Dressed in White section where he talks about talking at a Navy Chaplains Training School.

Comment: @Alamb Thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** The LDS Church posted a [new online resource solely about the temple garments](http://mormontopics.org/eng/garments). The video interviews are quite helpful here.

The garment originated back in Biblical times and the concept is related to the priestly garments worn by the tribe of Levi. There are Biblical and other LDS-scriptural references to the temple garments.

From the [Mormon Newsroom](http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/mormonism-101#C15):

> Biblical scripture contains many references to the wearing of special
>   garments. In the Old Testament the Israelites are specifically
>   instructed to turn their garments into personal reminders of their
>   covenants with God (see Numbers 15:37-41). Indeed, for some, religious
>   clothing has always been an important part of integrating worship with
>   daily living. Such practices resonate with Latter-day Saints today.

LDS doctrine states that in our day, temple ordinances have been restored to the earth in their fulness, offering great and eternal blessings to faithful members of the Church. Because of the restoration of these ordinances, temples and associated commandments may be found in the Doctrine and Covenants. So in a sense, it was a new revelation from God, but was seen on the earth before.

From [this article by Elder Carlos E. Asay of the Seventy](http://www.lds.org/ensign/1997/08/the-temple-garment-an-outward-expression-of-an-inward-commitment?lang=eng):

> It is written that “the white garment symbolizes purity and helps
>   assure modesty, respect for the attributes of God, and, to the degree
>   it is honored, a token of what Paul regarded as taking upon one the
>   whole armor of God (Eph. 6:13; cf. D&C 27:15). … Garments bear several
>   simple marks of orientation toward the gospel principles of obedience,
>   truth, life, and discipleship in Christ.”

However, discussion outside of the temple of the specific meanings of details of the garment and of the temple itself is not acceptable by Latter-day Saints and such discussion is often considered offensive because of the sacred nature of these things.

It is commonly said that the temple garment is "an outward expression of an inward commitment to follow the Savior" (see Asay's full article above).

Comment: Thanks, Matt. When did they originate in the LDS church?  Were they introduced by Joseph Smith?  Also, what about the symbols on them?

Comment: The ordinances, garments, etc, all came together, and yes it was introduced to the Saints by Joseph Smith. About halfway down in the "Historical Background" section from that linked article: "When the Church was restored to the earth in our day, the sacred priesthood ordinances associated with the holy temple were revealed anew to the Prophet Joseph Smith. The revelations he received included instructions about the garment." The next paragraph after this bit is really interesting about scriptural mentions.

Comment: It is important to note here that the endowment ceremony wasn't actually revealed until the Nauvoo era, though certainly specific temple doctrines were taught and revealed before then such as the sealing. Possibly the Temple Garment was before as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mason and Matt have answered this quite well, but there's another aspect to the garments that hasn't been brought up.

In the temple, Mormons are told that the garments represent the clothing given to Adam and Even when they were naked in the Garden of Eden, which can help us understand other things about the garment.

For example, Adam and Eve would either had to kill or witnessed the killing of an animal, whose skin would be used to make the clothing.  This would have been the first death that they saw, and is likely when they learned about the Atonement of Jesus Christ and the symbolism of animal sacrifice.  As such, the covering of skins taught them the power of making covenants and developing a relationship with God.  The animal skins do not symbolize modern-day garments; rather the modern-day garments are meant to remind us of the animal skins.

Comment: Interesting... It seems like the garments should be made of leather then to resemble the animal skins rather than the fig leaves that represented man's own efforts to cover over his own sin.

Comment: @Narnian The garments are also white so as to represent references to those having "purified their garments and whitened them in the blood of The Lamb." They also represent the "robes of righteousness" also referred to in the Bible. Certainly to make them resemble actual leather would break this aspect of the symbolism.

Comment: @Narnian: I've heard at least one linguist argue that the Hebrew phrase translated as "coats of skins" in Genesis should not be read that way--as leather--but instead as "skin-coats", or clothing worn directly against the skin, as an innermost layer.  (This ties in with Adam and Eve's shame over realizing that they were naked.)  I wish I could remember now where it was I saw that...

Answer (score 1):

Mormon Temple Garments can be of any material, including skins. Joseph Smith's were originally made of unbleached muslin.<sup>1</sup> They should be made of wool:

> Some of you have got an idea that wool will not do will not do; but let me inform you that when Peter came and sat in the Temple in Kirtland, he had on a neat woolen garment, nicely adjusted round the neck. What do sheep wear next the skin? Wool, of course. What do goats wear? Hair, for that is their nature. These are facts that are apparent to all who will look. <sup>2</sup>

The [Sufis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufism) wear a special garment made of wool. Suf means wool, and is the garment worn by early Muslim ascetics.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>James Allred as quoted in "Mormon Fundamentalism" by Max Anderson. Page 326; "Early Pioneer History" by Eliza M. A. Munson; "The Book of Remembrance of Elna Garner McReavy"</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Original Mormon Apostle, Heber C Kimball, Journal of Discourses, 9:376</sub>